# Rails: Get form to only render when certain conditions are met

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to get this loop to only render the reviews form for services which doesnt already have a review. I can't get it to function properly. Any ideas?

```
<% @services.each do |service| %>

  <% if service == @booked && !@hasReview %>
    <%= form_for(service, service.reviews.new) do |f| %>

      <label>Create review for</label> <%= label_tag service.title %>
      <div id="user_stars"></div>

      <div class form-group>
        <%= f.text_area :comment, rows: 3, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <%= f.hidden_field :service_id, value: service.id %>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>

    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The @booked and @hasReview actions are working correctly by themselves. So I guess Im setting it up wrongly with the IF

**EDIT:**

services_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @services = @user.services

    @booked = Booking.where("service_id = ? AND user_id = ?", @service.id, current_user_id).present? if current_user
    @reviews = @service.reviews
    @hasReview = @reviews.find_by(user_id: current_user_id) if current_user
  end
```

reviews_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @review = current_user.reviews.create(review_params)
    redirect_to request.referer
  end
```

Comment: Can you show the controller action where you define the instance variables?

Comment: Make your code simple, define a method model in service.rb as `def self.has_review?` which should return a boolean value. Now in view call easily as `<% unless service.has_review? %>`. This will make your code readable

Comment: Thanks guys, I updated with current controllers. Will try your suggestion asap @Sasidaran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic looks good, so I'm guessing your problem is with this part of your if statement:

```
if service == @booked
```

Judging from this line in your services_controller:

```
@booked = Booking.where("service_id = ? AND user_id = ?", @service.id, current_user_id).present? if current_user
```

it looks like the `@booked` instance variable is a boolean. So you're comparing a boolean to `service`, but it doesn't look like `service` is a boolean.

So you'll want to change the if statement so that you're comparing two equivalent types, and in your case you probably want to compare two boolean values.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really true. I changed that line to be just `<% if @booked && !@hasReview %>` and then it almost works. Its just that it is not part of the loop anymore so if there is a review for one service the form wont show up for the other services again.

Comment: Nevermind, just figured it out by making a simple change based on your answer Mark. Thanks so much!!